# Lua: Why the function didnt call?

Tags: user-interface, lua, roblox

Okay I am coding in lua a cheat for Roblox (just for fun).
But I created a function and the function got called!
I used the Library Kavo UI for the window.

But...
There is everything looks like in my code just that I change `function()` to `combat()`!

If I run this it doesn't show the UI!
But if I delete the function and the section it shows!

How do I fix it?

```lua
local Library = loadstring(game:HttpGet("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xHeptc/Kavo-UI-Library/main/source.lua"))()

local Window = Library.CreateLib("Ghoster", "Synapse")

local Combat = Window:NewTab("Combat")
local Movement = Window:NewTab("Movement")
local Exploit = Window:NewTab("Exploits")

local CombatSection = Combat:NewSection("Combat Options")
local MovementSection = Movement:NewSection("Movement Options")
local ExploitSection = Exploit:NewSection("Exploit Options")

function aimbot()
    loadstring(game:HttpGet(('https://gitlab.com/marsscripts/marsscripts/-/raw/master/CCAimbotV2'),true))()
end

CombatSection:NewButton("Aimbot", "Aims your enemies", aimbot()
    print("Loaded Aimbot")
end
```

Comment: `function` is a keyword, you can't change that as it would result in an syntax error. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Luke100000 i want to run aimbot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in misunderstanding the following syntax:

```lua
CombatSection:NewButton("Aimbot", "Aims your enemies", function()
    print("Loaded Aimbot")
end
```

`CombatSection:NewButton` receives 3 arguments, `"Aimbot"`, `"Aims your enemies"` and an **anonymous function**.

Just to ilustrate what you did, let's put that anonymous function into a variable instead:

```lua
local yourFunction = function()
    print("Loaded Aimbot")
end
```

And you changed that to (the invalid code)

```lua
local yourFunction = aimbot()
    print("Loaded Aimbot")
end
```

What you actually wanted is to pass aimbot as a function:

```lua
CombatSection:NewButton("Aimbot", "Aims your enemies", aimbot)
```

Or call `aimbot` from within that anomynous function:

```lua
CombatSection:NewButton("Aimbot", "Aims your enemies", function()
    aimbot()
    print("Loaded Aimbot")
end
```